# angular reading null value for existing nested object

Tags: html, angular, typescript, typeerror, nested-object

I have a fully populated object coming through from my server to my angular service. in postman I can see the entire object is there correctly.

even in the angular component that calls the service, when I JSON.stringify the object and print it to console it appears correctly. however, when I try to access that same object with angular in the view, I can only access the first level members of the object. when I try to access the existing nested object - I get:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined". I thought maybe this had to do with the fact that those fields *could* be null, so I tried using ngIf, and conditional chaining - but then it just doesn't show those fields.

I will note, that the way I am trying to access this object is through children components. there is one "profile page" component that houses it's two children - view profile, and edit profile. and the object in question is passed down from the parent, and the issue is when I try to view it in the children.

the service http call:

```
GetCustomer(username: string) {
  return this.http.get<Customer>(`${this.baseUrl}account/Customer/${username}`);
}
```

calling that in the "parent" profile component:

```
loadUserData() {
  if(this.user){

    if(!this.user.isAdmin){
      this.accountService.GetCustomer(this.user.userName).subscribe(
        c=>{this.customer = c}
      )}
```

the customer interface(.ts) and it's nested address interface:

```
export interface Customer {

  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  userName: string;

  email?: any;
  avatar?: any;

  creditInfo?: any;
  address: Address;
  orders: any[];

  phoneNumber: number;
}

export interface Address{

  id:number;
  country:string;
  city : string;
  street:string;
  houseNumber:number;
  zip:string;
}
```

parent template:

```
<div *ngIf="EditMode">
  <app-edit-profile [customer]="customer" 
  (customerChange)="UpdateCustomerData($event)" 
  (editMode)="toggleEditMode($event)"></app-edit-profile>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!EditMode">
  <app-view-profile [customer]="customer"  (editMode)="toggleEditMode($event)"></app-view-profile>
</div>
```

one of the children (they are both having the same issue):

```
export class ViewProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() customer?:Customer;
  @Output() editMode = new EventEmitter<boolean>();//this is to toggle between the children

  

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  toggleToEdit()
  {
    this.editMode.emit(true);
    this.showjson();
  }

  showjson()
  {
    if(this.customer)
    {
      var jace = JSON.stringify(this.customer);

      console.log(jace);
    }
  }

}
```

output of the json in console:

```
{"creditInfo":null,"adress":{"id":2,"country":"Peru","city":"Hong Kong","street":"Baker street","houseNumber":221,"zip":null},"orders":[],"phoneNumber":5000000,"id":6,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","userName":"jan","email":"John@gmail.com","avatar":null}
```

in the child template, when I try to read first level values like customer.email it shows them just fine, but when I try to get the inner properties of address I get the above error.

```
<section class="vh-100" *ngIf="customer">
...
 <p class="text-muted" >{{customer.firstName}}</p> // this works 

<p class="text-muted">{{customer.address.country}}</p>//this causes the error
```

kaboom!:

```
core.mjs:6461 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'country')
    at ViewProfileComponent_section_0_Template (view-profile.component.html:48:45)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:9593:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9459:1)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10584:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9483:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10630:1)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9255:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9509:1)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10584:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9483:1)
```

I tried to only include the relevant necessary things, hope I didn't miss anything important.

I have read a bunch of other posts I could find on the matter and none seemed to have the answer for me.

any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: `adress` != `address`

Comment: Yeah. You have a typo. The object you get from your backend does not have the `address` key (double *d*); it only has `adress` with a single d.

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time ?

Comment: thank you, you wonderful people. I was so sure I had triple checked all the spelling, yet there it is clear as day. I will go hide in shame and be even more careful before next time I post here...  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo alert! the `'address'` field is declared in your interface, and what you're trying to read. But, `'adress'` field is the field present in your JSON (customer data).

Answer (score 0):

You receive data with property adress while your interface is address, I think you need to communicate with the backend to fix the typo of property.